# RPostgreSQL Cannot Close Connections

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I have a shiny app that connects to a database using `RPostgreSQL`. At the end of the app the connection is closed and the driver should be unloaded but I get an error, warning me that the connection is not closed.

The code looks something like this:

```
 # in the app.R file, but not in the server function:
 drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
 con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "database1",
                host = "localhost", port = 5432,
                user = "user", password = "pw")

# in the server function:
foo <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from table1")

# at the end of the server function to disconnect when the app is closed:
session$onSessionEnded(function(){
    dbDisconnect(con)
    dbUnloadDriver(drv)
})
```

However, I get the error message: `Error in postgresqlCloseDriver(drv, ...): RS-DBI driver: (There are opened connections -- close them first)` this is displayed with the command `dbUnloadDriver(drv)`.

When I manually look for open connections with `dbListConnections()` I get a list with up to 16 open connections to the database. Notice, I only use `dbGetQuery` never `dbSendQuery` to avoid having to close connections.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Structure your code like this:

```
function()
{
  con <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL") # + other params
  on.exit(dbDisconnect(con))

  dbGetQuery("SELECT * FROM wherever") # or whatever you want to do
}
```

By using `on.exit`, the connection is guaranteed to be closed, whether or not an error occurred.

See also [How and when should I use on.exit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28300713/134830)

---

If you want, you can unload the driver using:

```
on.exit(dbUnloadDriver(drv), add = TRUE)
```

I suspect this may provide worse performance though, since you'll be unloading and reloading the driver each time you connect to the database.  Test this under your usage conditions if you are worried about this.

Comment: Do I have to unload the driver?

Comment: I simply do it like this:


library(RODBC)
dbconnection <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;Server=RSHUELL00193\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=TestDB;Uid=; Pwd=; trusted_connection=yes")
initdata <- sqlQuery(dbconnection,paste("select * from MyTable;"))
odbcClose(channel)


I have no problems with that at all.

Answer (score 10):

If you ran  `con <- dbConnect("PostgreSQL")` 
more than once, you have two open connections, but `con` was overwritten and now only references the second one. quick remedy: close all open PostgreSQL connections, no matter their name:
`lapply(dbListConnections(drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL")), function(x) {dbDisconnect(conn = x)})`
This runs the function dbDisconnect() on the list you get by checking all open connections with the driver dbDriver("PostgreSQL").

Comment: This also handles the case where a connection was opened and the script stopped because of an error and was then run again, opening another connection. This should be the accepted answer imo.

Comment: thanks for pointing out this additional benefit!